# Unable to get repr for queryset when call from Viewset

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to call a queryset for a model to add to my serializer using `objects.all()` but the debug said `Unable to set repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.Queryset'>`

Here is my viewset

```py
class TransactionReceiptViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                                viewsets.mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                                viewsets.mixins.ListModelMixin):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = base_serializers.TransactionReceiptSerializer
    queryset = models.TransactionReceipt.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return models.TransactionReceipt.objects.filter(user_profile=user)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(TransactionReceiptViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        receipt = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(receipt)

        product_qs = models.ProductReceipt.objects.all()
        products_data = base_serializers.ProductReceiptSerializer(
            product_qs, many=True)
        serializer.data['products'] = products_data
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and here is the model I tried to call for

```py
class ProductReceipt(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('Date of purchase', auto_now=True)
    transaction_receipt = models.ForeignKey(TransactionReceipt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "object created"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.product = Product()
        self.transaction_receipt = TransactionReceipt()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.amount = 1
        self.created_date = datetime.now()
        self.price = self.product.price_tag.price
```

When I debug the API, it said that `Unable to set repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.Queryset'>` in product_qs and nothing is returned

[image]

**Edit:**
I think that the Model have to do something with this. I have tried to create a `ModelViewSet` for ProductReceipt and it worked fine. But when i try to make the query manually. it somehow broke the mapping to the foreign key??? and return nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out that the product field is not set to null=True. And i have old data with that field point to nothing. There for it break when trying to query from the database. In short, i didn't migrate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Okey lets check a couple of things. First of all in your `ProductReceipt` class the `def save(self, **kwargs)` method is not calling super and that's a huge problem because the objects are not gonna be saved ever. Secondly, in the `ProductReceipt` class the `def __init__(self)` method you are assigning a new `Product` and a new `TransactionReceipt` to your `ProductReceipt` instance, but you are not setting the data of this two objects neither saving them in any place (maybe you should assign them inside save method and save them before calling super?).

Try this corrections and if it keeps not working we will another possible errors.

Finally, `def __str__(self)` is a string representation of your object, it will be a good implementation for example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name + ' x' + str(amount)
```

Comment: I have tried your solutions but it still show the error. I don't think it is a model error since what i am doing is getting the query of that object from the database to return the data to a serializer

Comment: Try to debug one ProductReceipt instance and check of any of its vars shows the same error.

Comment: I can still create and save new ProductReceipt. And i still can query it using another model viewset ```class ProductReceiptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = base_serializers.ProductReceiptSerializer
    queryset = models.ProductReceipt.objects.all()```

Comment: Try placing the query in the first line of the `retrieve` function just to check if it is correct there.

Comment: Do you have any pending migration? Run `django manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: I have finalized all model migration before doing API so no pending migration